# How do I close the app on chrome custom tab close

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I want the app to close when the user closes the custom tab.

I experimented with:

```
public interface ConnectionCallback {
        /**
         * Called when the service is connected.
         */
        void onCustomTabsConnected();

        /**
         * Called when the service is disconnected.
         */
        void onCustomTabsDisconnected();
    }
```

but wont work.

p.s. new to android/java

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to achieve? One possibility would be setting a flag when you open the Custom tab and using onResume() to check the flag and call finish() if it's being called after starting a Custom Tab. But I'm curious why you don't want the user to return to the host application.